# Did legal interracial marriage hit a nadir that was above 50% in 1948?

Tags: united-states, 20th-century, law, marriage

Did legal interracial marriage hit a nadir that was above 50% in 1948?

[image: XKCD marriage]

[Explain XKCD](http://web.archive.org/web/20180328104039/https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1431) for [this comic](http://xkcd.com/1431), which is currently down so I'm using an archive... said:

> Since the establishment of the United States, most states have had anti-miscegenation legislation in one form or another. Only nine states (Connecticut, New Hampshire, New York, New Jersey, Vermont, Wisconsin, Minnesota, Alaska, Hawaii) and the District of Columbia never enacted such legislation. Earlier repeal dates range from 1780 in Pennsylvania to 1887 in Ohio, though none were repealed between 1887 and 1948.

If I'm reading that right, then the nadir should actually be whenever the last anti-miscegenation law was passed, and then continue straight to 1948?

Comment: I think you are right by number of states, but the percentage of the population living in those states would vary by year.  It is difficult to calculate though.

Comment: I am not sure you infer anything pre-1948 from this text. We have to find out when each anti-miscegenation law was passed and repealed. Anyway, you won't have a straight line between 1887 and 1948 because of the variations in the population of the different states - and because of new states being created !

Comment: Most of the states allowing it before 1959 were in New England, and that area generally went down in total proportion of population in the first half of the 20th century.

Comment: You should quote the original source for the file as https://xkcd.com/1431/

Comment: @Pere - uh, like what I just did?